# Any idea why my print function prints and then runs forever?

Tags: c

Any idea why my print function prints and then runs forever before crashing?

```
void readDataFile(){

    FILE* fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
    int t=0;
    while(fp !=EOF){
        text[t] = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c",text[t]);
        t++;
    }

  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: because `fp` is never equal to `EOF`.

Comment: `fp` is set before your while loop and never being changed, therefore it will never be equal to `EOF`. `fp` needs to be updated either within the loop or via another function if one exists.

Comment: int fgetc(FILE *stream) returns an int value (assuming your buffer 'text[]' is int array).  When the return value from fgetc() returns as EOF, you then need to bail out of your while() loop.  As for the crash, you're getting buffer overflow from t > sizeof text[] array size.

Answer (score 3):

Check compiler warnings (e.g.: gcc -Wall file.c).  You should get a warning on the line "while(fp !=EOF){" that you are comparing a pointer to an integer.  The function works if you rewrite the while statement as:

```
while ((text[t] = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
    printf("%c",text[t]);
    t++;
}
```

Notice that you need to look for EOF in the character retrieved by fgetc, not in the file pointer fp.

Answer (score -2):

You need to start the loop with a condition that is true and then end it when it becomes false.  Otherwise the loop does not know when the condition becomes false i.e. it is always true and therefore it continues to loop.  My obs.

Comment: this is not answering the OPs question

Comment: I was trying to say that its an infinite loop.  Was I wrong?